# MVC4 many types of validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this `view`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterApartmentOwner", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new {placeholder = "Enter Your First Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { placeholder = "Enter Your Last Name"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { placeholder = "Enter Your Password"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { placeholder = "Enter Your Password Again"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNumber, new { placeholder = "Enter Your Mobile Number"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"  class="submit"/>
}
```

my problem is that the validation works just when the fields are empty, but i want the validation to discover when the two passwords are not equal, and when the mobilenumber is not numbers and so on. what should i do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at data annotations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could try the jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native nuget package. It's really easy to implement and will fit your needs.

**Installation**

Just add to you web.config file

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```

and in your Visual Studio go to **Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console**
Now in the console type

```
 PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native.MVC4
```

After you installed the package you should check out the demo site or download the
source from github for more information

[jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native Package](http://github.com/johnnyreilly/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native)

[jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native.Demo Site](http://jqueryvalidationunobtrusivenative.azurewebsites.net/)

[Using NuGet Package Manager](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

And in your case look at this **Examples**:

[EqualTo](http://jqueryvalidationunobtrusivenative.azurewebsites.net/Demo/EqualTo)

[Demo Validation](http://jqueryvalidationunobtrusivenative.azurewebsites.net/Demo)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC has some validation attributes like `RegularExpression` or `DataType` but they are not enough for some situations. In that case you need a mask for your textbox and the best one is [meio](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/). The site provides you lots of examples for different cases.

To check the equality of two passwords you need to write some javascript code or add a new rule in Jquery validation. [Comparing two passwords with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458417/comparing-two-passwords-with-jquery) might be helpful. The `Compare` attribute is another choice to compare two values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Data Annotations Extensions library it is available as nuget pagkage

Here is the site http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Nuget package http://www.nuget.org/packages/DataAnnotationsExtensions

Demos http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Home/Demos

Answer (score 0):

For the model you have created you can use data annotations and as per @kkern if u have enabled unobtrusive validation enabled and included all js file reference you can validate them by simply adding attributes in your properties. A Sample includes as following:

```
public class MyModel
{
[Required(ErrorMessage="First Name is Required")]
public string FirstName {get; set;}

[Required(ErrorMessage="")]
public string Password {get; set;}

[Compare("Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword {get; set;}
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{7,13}$", ErrorMessage = "Contact No must be digits only and length of 7-13.")]
public string MobileNo {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use could use in your model a self-validating approach:

```
public class TestModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (FirstName == null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("FirstName is mandatory.");
        }

        if (Password != PasswordConfirm)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Password confirmation does not match.");
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller you would have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        var errors = model.Validate(new ValidationContext(model, null, null));
        foreach (var error in errors)   
        {
            foreach (var memberName in error.MemberNames)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

More info about this approach: [How to force MVC to Validate IValidatableObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431478/how-to-force-mvc-to-validate-ivalidatableobject/6431986#6431986)